# Android - handle multiple clicks

Tags: android, button, onclick, logic

I have a functionality where user has a option to `flip the camera` from back to front and front to back on click of a button .

Something like -

```
  rlFlipCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switchCamera();

        }
    });
```

Now if the user clicks it `multiple times` , the function tries to switch the camera multiple times which leads to `lag/hang` on some devices . 
I want to prevent this using a logic -

```
1. If the user clicks the button multiple times , i will store the count .
2. If the count is odd number , i will  switch the camera .
3. If the count is even number , i will not switch the camera .
```

I am not sure how to get the button click count .
Please help.

Thanks .

Comment: I think your logic maynot suits. If you check the odd or even number of clicks, it will call the swicthCamera() method on the first attempt itself you cannot hold the method calling, until the user completes the clicks. So, better try to check the some click interval with SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()

Comment: @Srinivasan : yes the count will be based on an interval . If the user clicks 5 times in a span on 500 mili seconds then the count will be 5 . What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

This below sample may help you to solve the issue,

```
rlFlipCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime<UtilityClass.CLICK_INTERVAL)  {
            return;
      }
       mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
       switchCamera();

     }
    });
```

As per my understanding, here you dont need to maintain any count. If the user clicks the **rlFlipCamera** button, he wants to change the camera, he is not going to play with our application. If you follow the count then you maynot give right result to the user.Because,He don't know wether he clicked the button in odd or even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the best approach for this issue. Actually, you can consider about a flag variable like "isSwitching".

```
rlFlipCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!isSwitching) {
            switchCamera();
        }
    }
});
```